# Retrieve value in HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

```
HashMap details = new HashMap();
details = taskManager.getFormDetails(appSessionURI, accessToken);
System.out.println("Details :" + details);
```

Output:

`Details :{fileSize=-1590179396, fileId=38418026, fileHref=v1pre3/files/38418026, fileName=sorted_S1.bam, refgene=mm8, appSessionID=4646657}`

Here is my question. I would like to retrieve `fileId` and `refgene` from the Details. How can I do it?

Comment: Better if you provide the getFormDetail method or at least the class that is used by the hashmap returned by the function.

Comment: @Zan do you know how the hashmaps are used?

Comment: Did you look at the [JavaDoc for HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?

Comment: taking a look at some java APIs before coming here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is a key-value pair, i.e., a value is associated to a key.

Your code can be refactored as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> details = taskManager.getFormDetails(appSessionURI, accessToken);
//System.out.println("Details :" + details);
String fileName = (String)details.get("fileName");
String refGene = (String)details.get("refgene");
```

Comment: I'm glad to have helped. You must **first** understand the data structure of Collections, such as `List`, `Set`, `Map` and arrays and do some coding based on your understanding before trying to ask here. That's what the other developers were trying to show you in their comments.

Comment: Yup, I am trying to understand the data Structure also. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,the code `System.out.println("Details :" + details);` simply print your `HashMap` contents using `Key` and `Value` toString() method. You need to know the Object type of keys "fileId" and "refgene".I am assuming you are thinking it to be a String but it can be any Object with any custom implemented `toString()` method. If you know it is a String,you can get the value by using `details.get("refgene")` and `details.get("fileId")`

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is not wrong also =)